# Filling Dataset with Data Adapter query results C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working with C# and Asp.Net. I have following data adapter and Data set:

```
SqlDataAdapter da_Select_Matching_Records;
DataSet ds_for_showing_X_Rows_Cols = new DataSet();
```

I want to fill in the Data Set `ds_for_showing_X_Rows_Cols` with the query results. Here is my Code:

```
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");

da_Select_Matching_Records = new SqlDataAdapter("Select BusinessSector5.Description_DE, SubCategory.Kategorie "+
"FROM   Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 INNER JOIN "+
" SubCategory ON Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.ID INNER JOIN "+
" BusinessSector5 ON Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5.BusinessSector5ID = BusinessSector5.ID", con);

//Filling of Data Set
da_Select_Matching_Records.Fill(ds_for_showing_X_Rows_Cols, "Description_DE, Kategorie");
```

I am getting this error, on the line where I am filling the data set. I used the query in Sql Server management studio and its running OK.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword INNER.
```

Comment: You should paramaterize your queries too to avoid sql injection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In each line add a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a space at the end of this line:

```
"FROM   Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 INNER JOIN"+
```

i.e.

```
"FROM   Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 INNER JOIN "+
```

the same with this line too:

```
"SubCategory ON Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5.SubCategoryID = SubCategory.ID  INNERJOIN"+
```

You've also got no space between `INNER` and `JOIN`.

So to confirm, add a trailing space to all lines and a space between inner and join

Comment: Yes I added the space but still I am getting the same error. Then I also added space on other lines but still getting the same error.

Comment: A space on the end of this line too: Select BusinessSector5.Description_DE, SubCategory.Kategorie"+

Comment: A space between INNERJOIN i.e. INNER JOIN

Comment: Please can you add your updated code to the question? Just so I can re-check it.:)

Comment: I got it now. There was a space missing the end of this line.    "Select BusinessSector5.Description_DE, SubCategory.Kategorie". I added the space and its working now. Thanks

Comment: sorry i added to check all trailing spaces to the lines in question. pls accept the answer if it resolved. :)